# When can the function.name property be useful?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)

Each function has the `name` property. More than one function can have the same value for this property at the same scope. When can this property be useful? I didn't find an answer in MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). This is my code example:

```
var stuffs = [
    function stuff(){ return 'Hello, world!'; },
    function stuff(){ return 'Hello, JavaScript!'; },
];

console.log(stuffs[0].name);
console.log(stuffs[0]());

console.log(stuffs[1].name);
console.log(stuffs[1]());
```

Comment: Convenient in recursive situations, can call same function inside itself

Comment: Do `stuffs[0] = function(){...}` and you'll have a more accurate test for `.name`.

Comment: http://2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html

Comment: "This property is useful for debugging (its value shows up in stack traces) and some metaprogramming tasks (picking a function by name etc.)."